# Thymeleaf org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template

Tags: spring, templates, model-view-controller, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I've tried a lot of solutions but it just doesn't work. I'm using Intellij 2016.1.
I can't force the app to resolve templates.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/login/login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

**config**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.unibooker")
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean(name = "templateEngine")
public SpringTemplateEngine getTemplateEngine()
{
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(this.templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setMessageSource(this.messageSource());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());

    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver setupViewResolver()
{
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(this.getTemplateEngine());
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);

    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource()
{
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(3600);

    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver()
{
    CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("pl"));
    resolver.setCookieName("locale");
    resolver.setCookieMaxAge(86400);

    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)
{
    LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    interceptor.setParamName("locale");
    registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
}
```

[Project structure - IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUvWa.png)

I have tried to move templates to resources but still nothing. Please help. I have no more ideas how to fix this ... It worked earlier and then stopped.

Comment: is there a folder called `login` in `templates`?

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf Resolver will look under `templates/login/` for a `login.html` page. Based on your project structure and configuration, you rightly have a `login` folder inside template but you don't have a `login.html` inside the directory which is why the reason for the error.

Either create a `login.html` inside the login folder or use the `index.html` page which is already there. In your spring controller you should return the appropriate page.

For example,

Assuming that you need to show the login page your controller method should return,

```
return "login/login"  // to display login.html under `templates/login`
```

or

```
return "login/index"  // to display index.html under `templates/login`
```